# MUI DatePicker is showing beneath MUI drawer component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an MUI DatePicker component that is inside of an MUI drawer component. When you click on the date picker to pull up the calendar popup, it is rendering beneath the drawer.

[image]

I have tried to set the zIndex of the popper component through PopperProps but have had no luck.

Comment: please don't share your code as an image, instead copy and paste it. See here to why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/19529102

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Randolph's answer, disablePortal has resolved issue for me.

```
<DatePicker
{...props}
PopperProps={{
   disablePortal: true,
}}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the Popper show above the drawer component you need to supply to PopperProps an object with style property set to a high zIndex value. This value seemed to work perfectly fine for me.

```
<DatePicker
    {...props}
    PopperProps={{
       style: { zIndex: 1000000}}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it this way (MUI v5):

```
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';

<DatePicker 
      DialogProps={{
          style: { zIndex: 1325 } // it should be more than 1200
      }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE 2024

With **MUI V6** the **version 6.19.6**  https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/, When you are using drawer and DatePicker renders behind the drawer, You can use slotProps like this.

```
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";

<DatePicker
 className="w-full"
 label="Thru date"
 value={toDate}
 onChange={setToDate}
 slotProps={{
  field: { clearable: true },
  popper: {
    disablePortal: true,
  },
 }}
/>
```